# Can I use the Firebird DateAdd function in the Where clause?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

In firebird can I use the `DateAdd` function in the where clause?
I have the following sql;

```
select
  s.number,
  s.warranty_start
from
  serial_number s
where
  s.warranty_start > dateadd(year, -3, 'now')
```

I get error;

```
expression evaluation not supported
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your third parameter is invalid.

```
select
  s.number,
  s.warranty_start
from
  serial_number s
where
  s.warranty_start > dateadd(year, -3, current_timestamp)
```

`'now'` is a string literal that can only be used together with the `date` keyword, e.g. `date 'now'`. So instead of `current_timestamp` you would need to write `date`'now'`.

I prefer using standard SQL functions like `current_timestamp` over DBMS specific ones if both are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it is better to use standard SQL functions over DBMS specific ones.